# Properly merging branches Github

Tags: github, merge

I don't understand what is proper way of merging branches to master.I thought,I first create new pull request,then i choose master,check if there are conflicts,and then i merge branch(merge pull request);i also have some kind of validator that is checking if branches are merged well,and it says "branches were not merged properly"(i don't use local repository but directly on github make changes,merge branches,etc,and i am not using git bash,if that matters..)Can someone tell me is it ok to work with branches like that,or i must use git bash and local repository instead of directly working in github?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the message you are seeing: where and when is it appearing, and what is the exact wording of the message? (Please click [edit] under the question and add the details there.)

Comment: it is outside of github(checking if branches are merged ok).I am just wondering if i can work with branches like that,do i must have local repositories or not?

Comment: OK, so *where* outside of Github? What is this validator called? Who configured it? What does it say you are doing wrong? At the moment, your question is 1) Can I use Pull Requests in Github to merge things? Answer: Yes, that's what they're for. 2) Can I ignore the message I'm getting in some kind of validator? Answer: We have absolutely no way of knowing. It may be telling you something very important; it may be saying that you merged in a different "style" than the validator is configured to check for; it may be broken; or you may have misunderstood the message.

Comment: i solved problem,thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there anything others could learn from your experience? If so, would you consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others searching in the same situation won't have to scratch their heads for as long?